Get the first character making a regular expression test fail
I use the following function to examine whether an entry contains invalid characters. The regular expression test() function return false when the input string contains excluded character(s).  Is there any way to return the first character/character(s) making the test fail?
function isContainInvalidCharacter(str) {
    //--- Allowable characters in string a-z, A-Z, 0-9, Space @,.$)\/(-%:
    if ( /^[A-Za-z0-9\p{sc=Hani}\s,.@$)\/(%:-]+$/u.test(str) == false) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}


I guess you need to negate your allowed-class and get it with match (JS demo).

@bobblebubble: You might as well not to use RegExp.prototype.test at all (demo)

You guys saved my day.  Could you vote and help re-open my question?

Thank you @CasimiretHippolyte, very nice and short one! newcoder I already voted and also don't understand the very fast closure - don't worry, that happens quite often here. Most importantly you got some ideas now.

Happy to learn from you guys.  Thanks a lot @bobblebubble.  Stackoverflow is hard to ask question nowaday.

You can negate the allowed-class and use match() for that. Now we want to match the first "not-allowed" character that can appear anywhere in the string, so the ^ start and $ end anchors need to be removed. To get just one character further remove the + quantifier.
As per @CasimiretHippolyte's comment even test() can be omitted (JS demo).


function hasInvalidCharacter(str)
{
  //--- Allowable characters in string a-z, A-Z, 0-9, Space @,.$)\/(-%:
  return str.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9\p{sc=Hani}\s,.@$)\/(%:-]/u) || false;
}

console.log(hasInvalidCharacter("f!oo"))



